# Suitescript error: TypeError: Cannot set property "JSZipSync" of undefined

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have the following script where I am getting an error message:

> org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot set property
> "JSZipSync" of undefined to
> "org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction@6e57e155"
> (/SuiteScripts/Suitelet to Excel.js#17(eval)#2)

According to Netsuite support, there are no issues with the script and they are not getting this error message

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */

define(["N/search", "N/file", "N/https"], function (search, file, https) {
  function onRequest(context) {
   

    // Load the xlsx library from the CDN
    var response = https.get({
      url: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.full.min.js",
    });
    var script = response.body;
    eval(script);

    // Replace this with the ID of the saved search you want to run
    var searchId = "customsearch_my_saved_search";

    // Run the search and get the results
    var searchResult = search.load({
      id: searchId,
    });
    var searchRows = searchResult.run().getRange({
      start: 0,
      end: 1000,
    });

    // Create an array to hold the data for the Excel file
    var data = [];

    // Add the column names as the first row
    var columnNames = [];
    searchResult.columns.forEach(function (column) {
      columnNames.push(column.label);
    });
    data.push(columnNames);

    // Add the search results to the data array
    searchRows.forEach(function (row) {
      var rowData = [];
      searchResult.columns.forEach(function (column) {
        rowData.push(
          row.getValue({
            name: column.name,
          })
        );
      });
      data.push(rowData);
    });

    // Create the Excel file
    var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet1");
    var binaryData = XLSX.write(wb, {
      type: "binary",
      bookType: "xlsx",
    });
    var fileName = "search_results.xlsx";
    var folderId = -4; // -4 represents the "Home" folder in the file cabinet
    var file = file.create({
      name: fileName,
      fileType: file.Type.EXCEL,
      contents: binaryData,
      folder: folderId,
    });

    // Send the file as a response to the user
      context.response.writeFile({
        file: file,
        isInline: true,
      });
    });
  }
  return {
    onRequest: onRequest,
  };
});
```

I can't tell where I am going wrong?

The JSZipSync is a function in the xlsx.full.min.js library which I believe I have loaded correctly.

I have also tried storing this file in the filing cabinet and referencing that instead of a link to the CDN website.

The same error message is generated in both cases